# How to work around an invalid certificate error using Selenium ChromeDriver?

Tags: ssl-certificate, selenium-chromedriver

I'm trying to load a webpage using Selenium ChromeDriver. It worked for the past 2 weeks until today I get an error about my connection not being secure and the page doesn't load. By making some research it seems to have something to do with the SSL certificate. However if I launch the same page in Chrome without using Selenium, the connection shows as secure.

I tried to use `DesiredCapabilities` and `ChromeOptions` to launch the driver with different options, but none seems to be working up to now.

This code shows a resume of all `DesiredCapabilities` and `ChromeOptions` I tried up to now.

```
    ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
    options.setAcceptInsecureCerts(true);
    options.setUnhandledPromptBehaviour(UnexpectedAlertBehaviour.ACCEPT);
    options.addArguments("--allow-insecure-localhost");
    options.addArguments("--ignore-certificate-errors");
    options.addArguments("--allow-running-insecure-content");

    DesiredCapabilities capabilities = DesiredCapabilities.chrome();
    capabilities.setCapability(CapabilityType.ACCEPT_SSL_CERTS, true);
    capabilities.setCapability(CapabilityType.ACCEPT_INSECURE_CERTS, 
    true);

    capabilities.setCapability(CapabilityType.SUPPORTS_NETWORK_CONNECTION, 
    true);
    capabilities.setCapability(ChromeOptions.CAPABILITY, options);  

    wDriver = new ChromeDriver(capabilities);
```

I don't get any different results using these options or not. I get no error message besides a windows pop up in Chrome on the left of navigation bar saying the connection is not secure.

[This is the error showing on the browser](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lnYHj.png)

What am I missing?